# wordpress settings select not saving

Tags: wordpress, select, themes, wordpress-theming

Hey I am trying to create a select option similar to this tutorial by Alecaddd that I've been following [Alecadd Gibhub](https://github.com/Alecaddd/Sunset-theme/tree/master/Lesson%2051). I've tried outputting a select option with the following code, it displays but doesn't save the selected option.

```
function sa_comments_callback(){
$options = get_option( 'postpage_comments' );
$comments = array( 'Post', 'Page', 'Both', 'None' );

$output = '<select name="">';
foreach( $comments as $comment ){


    $output .= '<option id="' . $comment . '" value="' . $comment . '"' . selected( @$options[$comment] ) . '">' . $comment . '</option>';

}
$output .= '</select>';
echo $output;
```

}

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you use the  [update_option](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option) ? From what i can see the code should work. Also try to add some default value at the [selected](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/selected) function

Comment: Not entirely sure where i'd add those in.